# How to update one to many relation table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

My Update SQL statement that I mentioned below is working correctly but when I try to update using php form and hit submit button. So, Its not working. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, please? And the table relationship is one to many.

```php
if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {
    $expID = $_POST['expID'];
    $start = $_POST['dateStart'];
    $end = $_POST['dateEnd'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $org = $_POST['org'];
    $des = $_POST['des'];

    $sql = "UPDATE exp,desExperience SET exp.dateStart='$dateStart',
                  exp.end = '$end ',
                  exp.title ='$title',
                  exp.org ='$org',
                  desExperience.des  = '$des'
                 WHERE exp.ID_EP = desExperience .ID_DesExp AND ID_EP='$expID '";

    $exe = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($exe === true) {
        echo 'updated record';
    } else {
        echo "Not updated";
    }
}
```

When I hit submit button record is not updating and also I am not getting any error.

Comment: Learn about prepared statement to prevent SQL injection

Comment: *So, Its not working* is not an error description. Do you get any error? Where do you check for sql errors?

Comment: Remove the blanks afer the variables  (`exp.end = '$end ',`  --> `exp.end = '$end'`)

Comment: @Jens Please just show me where I am wrong with this code.I know about a prepared statement. For now, I just want to update record into one to many relationships tables.

Comment: If you know about prepared statements then why not use them immediately? It's not difficult, you can make your code more secure and also reduce the risk of some silly syntax errors. Plus if you do it properly the first time you don't have to go back and re-write and also re-test it all later to make it releasable. If this code will be used by anyone except you then you might as well save yourself the time and fix it now. If it won't, you should still write it properly so you get into good habits for when you need to do it for real.

Answer (score -1):

Add `}` end of the line and clear all post data with escape_string

```
$expID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['expID']);
```

Comment: thanks but its not working.The problem here its not updating into database.

Comment: Your sql statement is wrong.look at this example: $sql= 'UPDATE exp,desExperience SET
            exp.dateStart="$start",
            exp.end = "$end",
            exp.title = "$title",
            exp.org = "$org",
            desExperience.des = "$des"
        WHERE exp.ID_EP = desExperience.ID_DesExp AND ID_EP="$expID" 
    ';  //$dateStart - undefined variable and variable in single quoute .